# What does it mean Ethernet L2 switching?

Tags: ethernet, switching

can someone please tell me or provide some links to materials that talk about Ethernet L2 switching?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FWIW this kind of question is OT for SO. Also note that afaict this is trivially searchable on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's based on [packet switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_switching) - a switch reads a packet's destination MAC address and decides on which port it is forwarded.